# Future<List<dynamic>> cannot be assigned to List<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart

Getting the error (title) when I try to assign the return of this method to a widget parameter. The `suggestions:` is expect a `List<dynamic>` not a `Future<List<dynamic>>`. Is FutureBuilder the only way? The `AutoCompleteTextField` in this widget is a type ahead so will be calling getLocationSuggestionsList every .5 seconds after keystrokes stop (not sure if that matters in answering this question).

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: new Center(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      new Column(children: <Widget>[
        searchTextField = AutoCompleteTextField<dynamic>(
            suggestions: getLocationSuggestionsList("sd"),
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
           .....



Future<List<dynamic>> getLocationSuggestionsList(String locationText) async {
    List<String> suggestionList = List();
    Map suggestionsKeyValuePairs = Map<String, String>();
    dynamic data = await GoogleMapsServices.getAddressPrediction(
      locationText,
      LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
    );
    if (data != null) {
      for (dynamic predictions in data.predictions) {
        suggestionsKeyValuePairs[predictions.description] = predictions.placeId;
        if (!suggestionList.contains(predictions.description))
          suggestionList.add(predictions.description);
      }
      return suggestionList;
    } else {
      return [''];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The cause for this error is that the suggestions parameter expects a List not a Future.

What you can do is create a state variable and assign the result of your `getLocationSuggestionsList()` function to that with a `setState()` call or any other state management mechanism so that whenever the state changes the UI builds again with the relevant data.

```
class YourClass extends StatefulWidget {
 ///
}

class _YourClassState extends State<YourClass>{

   /// Your state variable here. Initialize with data that will be showing if actual data not available.
   List<dynamic> suggestionList = ["];


   initState(){
     /// call you get suggestion function on init or any other lifecycle methods as per your need, may be inside build
     getLocationSuggestionsList("sd");
     super.initState();
   }


   @override
   Widget build(context){
       return AutoCompleteTextField<dynamic>(
            suggestions: suggestionList,
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
            decoration: new InputDecoration()
            /// ....
       );

   }



   void getLocationSuggestionsList(String locationText) async {
    List<String> sList = List();
    Map suggestionsKeyValuePairs = Map<String, String>();
    dynamic data = await GoogleMapsServices.getAddressPrediction(
      locationText,
      LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
    );
    if (data != null) {
      for (dynamic predictions in data.predictions) {
        suggestionsKeyValuePairs[predictions.description] = predictions.placeId;
        if (!sList.contains(predictions.description))
          sList.add(predictions.description);
      }
    } else {
     sList =  [''];
    }

    setState((){
      suggestionList = List;
      /// This will render your UI again with updates suggestionList
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The getLocationSuggestionsList needs to be called on almost each keystroke. Does that change you solution?

Comment: No . you can call it on each keystroke using on changed of some widget.

Answer (score 1):

`getLocationSuggestionsList()` is async and return a future, if you want to get the result (`List<dynamic>`), you need to call it with `await` keyword.

```
await getLocationSuggestionsList("sd")
```

But, this is only possible into async functions/methods.

You can resolve this by many ways:

- Use FutureBuilder
- Do it with reactive programing architecture (Bloc, Rx, raw streams, etc...)
- Do it like krishnakumarcn ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/62187158/13569191